# I need to count the number of elements (words) separated by space in R

Tags: string, count, words

I have this string for instance,

> s
>   [1] "problem delet detach partit db2 luw v9 7 recent prod environ problem drop detach partit give error db21034e command process sql statement valid command line processor command sql process return sql20285n statement command allow tabl name schemanam tablenam jan1 detach depend asynchron partit detach oper complet reason code 2 sqlstate 55057 research find ibm say need restart instanc solv issu link think seen mani incid describ pleas help issu thank advanc http www 01 ibm com support docview wss uid swg21515721 "

I just need to count the number of words in s.. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
String test="your sample text";
System.out.println("number of words starting on s : "+test.split(" s").length);
```

split(String **regex**) - return array of strings split by **regex**.

in a place of **"regex"** use **" s"** (single space before **"s"**) starting of new words in **S**.

Comment: nice use case but you can give more general case example